# Sharepoint Parent/Child list Dynamic View

Tags: list

I just started using SP 2010, I need to implement a process using SP, so I created a 
parent/child list, and modify the dispform of the parent list to add child list as a web part to it. The problem is now when I click an item in the parent list, all the item of child list is displayed to the item. But I just want the item of child list with the same look up value of the item to be displayed. For example, the item in parent list has a ID of 2, I want only the item with ID 2 in the child list to be displayed when I open the parent item. Is there any good approaches to achieve the function?

Thanks

Comment: Here are some ideas for creating parent-child relationships via SharePoint lists: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into [WebPart Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178187%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It's very easy to connect two WebParts together as explained here:

- [Connect data in Web Parts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/windows-sharepoint-services-help/connect-data-in-web-parts-HA010024105.aspx)
- [ConnectWeb Parts in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

When you have two list view WebParts on one page you just have to send the filter value of the one list to the other list and they will work together. Whether this will work on a DispForm.aspx I'm not sure - you can check on a regular page for testing purposes though.